# Why does my Octave subplot disappear?

Tags: plot, octave, subplot

When I plot in octave I can left-click two points in the plot and it will zoom in on that section. However when I create two side-by-side plots in Octave and try to zoom in the left plot disappears. Is this not the correct way to navigate subplots in Octave?

Following is an example of commands that exhibit the behavior.

```
x = [10:1:100];
subplot(1,2,1);
plot(x);
subplot(1,2,2);
plot(x);
```

Comment: What plot viewer are you using? I think you can check this with `getenv("GNUTERM")`.

Comment: @Engineero It only appears to happen with gnuplot. I have since discovered that it works as expected when using fltk so it must be a bug.

Comment: When creating several subplots, Octave says: "the next call to subplot activates the second subplot area, but does not re-partition the figure." So Octave activates the last subplot. If you try and zoom in/out it will be on this last plot. Maybe your axes are linked?